# Using a method to search a match in a list in Java

Tags: java, string, list, methods

I am trying to create a program that will get input from a user using a package called 'bulletproof' (done, works fine) but I am getting an infinite loop error when I find a match. I am a bit over my head and I do not feel I quite comprehend why my code is not working. I am not looking for a direct answer as I am trying to learn this, but any help would be sincerely appreciated. Thank you, my code is as follows.

--edit--
i got the program working. Thank you all for your help, you folks are tremendous.

```
import bulletproof.*;

public class A26_1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BPScanner kb = new BPScanner();
    String reservedWordToCheck = kb.getStringFromUser("Enter a word to see if it's reserved or enter leave: ");

    System.out.println(ReservedWordChecker(reservedWordToCheck));
}

public static String ReservedWordChecker(String reservedWordToCheck) {
    String[] table = {
            "abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const",
            "continue", "default", "do", "double", "enum", "extends", "final", "finally", "float",
            "for", "goto", "if", "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native",
            "new", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static", "strictfp", "super",
            "switch", "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "try", "void", "volatile", "while"
        };

    while (true) {                      
        if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase("leave"))
            break;                
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
            if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase(table[i])) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }               
            if (found)
                System.out.println("Yeah, " + reservedWordToCheck + ", is reserved as a Java identifier.");
            else
                System.out.println("Nope, the word " + reservedWordToCheck + ", isn't reserved. Go hog wild.");                      
        }      
        System.out.println("OK BYE");
    } return reservedWordToCheck;
}
```

}

Comment: general input? Like if I put in a word on that list, it should match and say "yeah" and then the word ", is a reserved word.". The program checks against the list provided inside the method. I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Hi, a good practice is to use the string equality functions as presented: if ("leave".equalsIgnoreCase(reservedWordToCheck)). Doing that you prevent that a NullPointerException occurs. If reservedWordToCheck is null the condition is false as we expect but the RuntimeException is avoided.

Comment: You should also think in modify your code to have only one loop, you do not need the external while. The if before the for and finally you can simplify your code doing if (table[i].equalsIgnoreCase(reservedWordToCheck)) { return reservedWordToCheck;}. Also remember to declare the String [] Table as a constant outside your method is not desirable to create a new instance each time you use the ReservedWordChecker. I also think that the method shoul be called existsReservedWord and could return a boolean, not the word that you are searching for.

Answer (score 3):

I think easiest way to do is -

```
public static boolean ReservedWordChecker(String reservedWordToCheck) {
    String[] table = {
            "abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const",
            "continue", "default", "do", "double", "enum", "extends", "final", "finally", "float",
            "for", "goto", "if", "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native",
            "new", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static", "strictfp", "super",
            "switch", "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "try", "void", "volatile", "while"
        };

       for (String data : table) {
            if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I heard I could cast it to boolean, but I didn't think it would be that simple. That helped me SO much! Thank you!

Comment: Personally, I'm a big believer in one entry and one exit point, but that's just me

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the following code outside your `for` loop because your `for` breaks when you get a match but your `while` loop continues to run

```
 if (found){
            System.out.println("Yeah, " + reservedWordToCheck + ", is reserved as a Java identifier.");
            break;
 }
 else{
            System.out.println("Nope, the word " + reservedWordToCheck + ", isn't reserved. Go hog wild.");
            break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not breaking out of while loop after you found the match: -

You should move your `if-else` out of your `for-loop` and add break to your `if`, which will break your `while` whether or not a match is found: -

```
for (int i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
    if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase(table[i])) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
} 
if (found) {
     System.out.println("Yeah, " + reservedWordToCheck + 
                        ", is reserved as a Java identifier.");
     break;
} else {
     System.out.println("Nope, the word " + reservedWordToCheck + 
                        ", isn't reserved);
     break;
}
```

But I don't understand, why you need a `while` loop here. Its sort of meaningless. Your `for-loop` is enough to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` within `for` loop breaks the `for` loop not `while`. So, the while loop continues infinitely.

See the changes, i've done and it should work fine.

```
while (true) 
{
    .......
    .......

for (int i=0; i < table.length; i++) 
{                
    if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase(table[i])) 
    {                    
        found = true; 
        break; // remove break from here          
    }

    if (found)                    
    {
        System.out.println("Yeah, " + reservedWordToCheck + ", is reserved as a Java identifier.");
        break;
    }                                  
} // end for
if(found)
{
    System.out.println("OK BYE");
}
else                    
{
    System.out.println("Nope, the word " + reservedWordToCheck + ", isn't reserved. Go hog wild.");
}
break;
} // end while
```

But, you don't need `while(true)` construct to check this. only the `for` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are not breaking at the right position:

```
for (int i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
    if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase(table[i])) {
        found = true;
        break; <--
    }               
    if (found)
        System.out.println("Yeah, " + reservedWordToCheck + ", is reserved as a Java identifier.");
    else
        System.out.println("Nope, the word " + reservedWordToCheck + ", isn't reserved. Go hog wild.");                      
}
```

When the word is found, you break out of the for loop and you do not display anything but `OK BYE`.

More over I don't understand why you put an infinite loop there?

Something like that would work:

```
public static String ReservedWordChecker(String reservedWordToCheck) {
    String[] table = { ... };

    if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase("leave")) {
        break;
    }

    boolean found = false;
    for (String entry : table) {
        if (entry.equalsIgnoreCase(reservedWordToCheck)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        System.out.println("Yeah, " + reservedWordToCheck + ", is reserved as a Java identifier.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nope, the word " + reservedWordToCheck + ", isn't reserved. Go hog wild.");                      
    }
    System.out.println("OK BYE");
    return reservedWordToCheck;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That is because your unlabeled break only finish the for statement but the while(true) will continue iterating.

The solution could be using a labeled break as below:

```
  search: 
  while (true) {                      
        if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase("leave"))           
           break;                
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
            if (reservedWordToCheck.equalsIgnoreCase(table[i])) {
                found = true;
                break search;
            }               
            if (found)
                System.out.println("Yeah, " + reservedWordToCheck + ", is reserved as a Java identifier.");
            else
                System.out.println("Nope, the word " + reservedWordToCheck + ", isn't reserved. Go hog wild.");                      
        }      
        System.out.println("OK BYE");
    } return reservedWordToCheck;
```

For further information read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html